# SIGILL signal is sent to my Android app

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rtsp

In my application I want to be able to play streaming video (by way of RTSP protocol).
I found open RTSP stream: `rtsp://red7blue.de/Primetime` and tried to play it. But my application is being terminated by signal SIGILL while trying to play video. I'm using libffmpeg.so and cause ofthe SIGILL signal is located in the code of this library.
Look at what I got in logs:

```
D/dalvikvm(  217): Trying to load lib /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so 0x43757d68
D/dalvikvm(  217): Added shared lib /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so 0x43757d68
D/dalvikvm(  217): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so 0x43757d68
D/dalvikvm(  217): Trying to load lib /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libplayer-4.so 0x43757d68
D/dalvikvm(  217): Added shared lib /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libplayer-4.so 0x43757d68
D/PlayerActivity(  217): FILE TO OPEN: rtsp://red7blue.de/Primetime
D/dalvikvm(  217): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'open' (wrong CL)
D/dalvikvm(  217): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libexif.so' for 'open' (wrong CL)
D/dalvikvm(  217): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libFFTEm.so' for 'open' (wrong CL)
I/DEBUG   (   27): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   27): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.6/Donut/20842:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   27): pid: 217, tid: 217  >>> my.apps.package <<<
I/DEBUG   (   27): signal 4 (SIGILL), fault addr 81337fb0
I/DEBUG   (   27):  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000001  r3 00000001
I/DEBUG   (   27):  r4 00000001  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   27):  r8 7fffffff  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 20000000
I/DEBUG   (   27):  ip 00000000  sp bee438a0  lr 81337f68  pc 81337fb0  cpsr 80000010
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #00  pc 00337fb0  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #01  pc 00338564  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #02  pc 003368b8  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #03  pc 00079f74  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #04  pc 0007a040  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #05  pc 002c5780  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #06  pc 002d6bc4  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #07  pc 002c67d0  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #08  pc 003110a0  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #09  pc 00317ac4  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #10  pc 003197bc  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #11  pc 00316d04  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #12  pc 00319448  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #13  pc 002c67d0  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #14  pc 002c6fe0  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #15  pc 00004a28  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libplayer-4.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #16  pc 00007d08  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libplayer-4.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #17  pc 0000e434  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #18  pc 00040b0e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #19  pc 000432b6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #20  pc 00013198  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #21  pc 00017be4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #22  pc 0001762c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #23  pc 000529a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #24  pc 00059eda  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #25  pc 00013198  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #26  pc 00017be4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #27  pc 0001762c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #28  pc 0005282c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #29  pc 0003f790  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #30  pc 00031caa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):          #31  pc 0002a804  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   27): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43860  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43864  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43868  20000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4386c  8135cb94  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43870  20000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43874  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43878  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4387c  20000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43880  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43884  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43888  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4388c  8135ca5c  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43890  bee43898  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43894  81337f68  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43898  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4389c  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (   27): #00 bee438a0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438a4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438a8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438ac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438b0  3ff00000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438b4  afc1d8f4  /system/lib/libm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438b8  afc1d868  /system/lib/libm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438bc  001f750c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438c0  8146ab20  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438c4  0000001c  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438c8  8b9e9309  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438cc  8b9e9309  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438d0  3fa56e5f  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438d4  afc0e3bc  /system/lib/libm.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438d8  2d87a4ea  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438dc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438e0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438e4  bee43928  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438e8  bee4392c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438ec  ffffffbe  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438f0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438f4  bee43928  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438f8  bee4392c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee438fc  bee43968  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43900  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43904  7fffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43908  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4390c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43910  20000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43914  81338568  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27): #01 bee43918  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4391c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43920  7fffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43924  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43928  8145fe10  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4392c  81336698  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43930  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43934  8146ab50  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43938  001f74f0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4393c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43940  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43944  bee43968  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43948  7fffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee4394c  8145fe34  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43950  8145fe10  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
I/DEBUG   (   27):     bee43954  813368bc  /data/data/my.apps.package/lib/libffmpeg.so
D/Zygote  (   29): Process 217 terminated by signal (4)
I/ActivityManager(   65): Process my.apps.package (pid 217) has died.
I/WindowManager(   65): WIN DEATH: Window{43846460 my.apps.package/my.apps.package.MainActivity paused=false}
```

As I guess one of the causes of SIGILL signal may be the try to perform privileged instruction. RTSP is a network protocol. It's meaning that ffmpeg.so tries to access media stream using network. Maybe some special permissions should be specified for that? In my app I have the only explicit permission - `android.permission.INTERNET` 
Should I specify something else?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error, soon i realised that the problem was because i have compiled the program for armv-7 platform and i tried runnig it on arm v5. You may comment the portion in Application.mk which says something like this #APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

Answer (score 1):

use arm-eabi-objdump disassemble the libplayer-4.so and libffmpeg.so. check address around 7d08, 4a2b in libplayer-4.so and 2c6fe0 in libffmpeg.

After the address found, find out the label. It's function name.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. I will do this as a last chance to solve my problem - if other efforts won't help. I'm not sure I fizz to dig into intricacies of dissassembled listings and C-sources. So first I will try more high-level investigations and experiments.